# Is Python's weakref a performance issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, weak-references

I have an object structure where there are mutual references (its finite element, where the results need to reference the nodes and elements, and the nodes and elements need to reference the results).

I am using weakrefs to avoid setting up a permanent referencing loop which prevents garbage collection.

During profiling, however, I am finding that clearing these weakrefs is surprisingly expensive - behind only scipy's minimise (whose performance is entirely understandable).

I've improved performance by about 35% by representing unused weakref's as None:

Original:

```
  def clear_results(self):
        self._results = lambda: None    # Mimics weakref behaviour, but returns None
```

35% faster:

```
def clear_results(self):
    self._results = None    # Requires check in the public accessor of self._results
```

It is also the *destruction* of the weakref which appears to take the time - the creation of the weakref doesn't even make the profiling list.

This doesn't seem intuitively reasonable - am I missing something?

Comment: "permanent referencing loop which prevents garbage collection." [This is no longer the case since Python 3.4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/). Which Python version and implementation are you using?

Comment: Wow - I'm using 3.8, but I've only changed relatively recently.  What does that leave the use of weakref as, then - doesn't that make them completely redundant?

Comment: From the docs: ["A primary use for weak references is to implement caches or mappings holding large objects, where it’s desired that a large object not be kept alive solely because it appears in a cache or mapping."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) Breaking up reference cycles was more of a historical by-product of CPython's garbage collection scheme.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if you want to post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, so I don't think that is appropriate.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that is very noble, but it does mean that from a practical point of view it means that this question is likely to go unanswered.  The answer is effectively "yes, because it is something that does nothing, but takes time".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, the cyclic garbage collector has been around since Python 2.0, I'm pretty sure. Or something like that. That PEP just improved the way finalizers were dealt with, i.e. `__del__` AFAIKT

Comment: @MikeSadler Point is, I can't tell you *why* it's taking *so much* more time. In CPython (and others probably), ``weakref`` has a builtin optimisation for the primary types that you appear to be using (``ref``, ``ReferenceType`` and ``ProxyType``). These should be a bit not excessively slower than regular references.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Prior to 3.4, reference cycles could indeed be broken if they did not contain a finaliser (``__del__`` or equivalent C-slot). Since innocently looking things such as generators have a finalizer, it was pretty easy to accidentally have an uncolletable cycle anyways. So prior to 3.4, weakref was probably not needed already, but not it definitely is not needed. (Can't edit my initial comment to add this distinction.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the performance might be a misunderstanding of the profiling results on my part.  Although I have shaved a lot of time off by reworking that area, I'm no longer convinced it was the weakrefs *themselves*.  I'll post comments for each speed-up below:

Comment: 1) my "weakref replicator" (self._results = lambda: None) seemed to take the time, rather than the clearing of the weakref.  Replacing this with just self._results = None saved a fair amount of time.

Comment: 2) I was using a listcomp to actually clear the results: [item.clear_results() for item in items].  It turns out that this is much slower than a straight loop - possibly in part because I don't need to collect the results.

Comment: 3) Even after removing weakrefs completely, clear_results() still takes a surprising amount of time, in spite of it being a single line of "self._results = None".  I'm not sure why yet, but it proves that weakref wasn't the problem here.

Comment: @MikeSadler yes, don't use list-comprehensions for side-effects. List comprehensions are for building lists with mapping/filtering operations. Even in those cases, the difference in performance is negligible, they are for readability not performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to post this synopsis to close-out the question.  Almost all of the information comes from @MisterMiyagi, and my thanks and all credit goes to him.

The short answer is "no" - the weakrefs were not causing the performance issues that I was seeing.  What's more, as @MisterMiyagi points out, they weren't even needed at all, since more recent versions of Python than I had started on (V1.9) cope with the problem that I was using weakref to protect against (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).

I was able to improve performance on two unrelated issues, which might be of interest to others:

1. My "weakref replicator" (`self._results = lambda: None`) was surprisingly slow. Replacing this with just self._results = None saved a fair amount of time.
2. I was using a listcomp to clear the results: `[item.clear_results() for item in items]`. It turns out that this is much slower than a straight loop - possibly in part because I don't need to collect the results.